# Binding Dictionary<String, List<String>> to DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-forms-designer

How can I bind a `Dictionary<String, List<String>>` to the DataGridView in C#?

Something like:

```cs
var l = from row in listValues select new { Item = row.key, Elements = row.Value };
DatagridView.dataSource = l;
```

Answer (score 1):

Erk, I wouldn't.. but you could if you wanted:

```
yourDataGridView.DataSource = dictionary.Select(x => new {
  PK = x.Key,
  Name = x.Value[0];
  Email = x.Value[1];
  Address = x.Value[2];
}).ToArray();
```

Assuming that the `List<string>` in the dictionary's value is a list of 3 strings, being the person's name, email and address. i.e. the dictionary was created like/looks like:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, List<string>> {
  {"person1", new List<string>{ "anna", "anna@mail.com", "1 the street" }},
  {"person2", new List<string>{ "caius", "caius@gmail.com", "2 the street" }}
};
```